# SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor constructor throwing error on other machine

Tags: c#, .net, 7zip

The same code in .net winforms application is working on my machine while crashing on other machine with the following exception.

```
SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,
"x86", "7z.dll"));
var extractor = new SevenZipExtractor("myfile.7z", "abcd");
```

Myfile.7z have some text files with Unicode text

See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

> System.ArgumentException: Cannot marshal: Encountered unmappable character.
>          at System.String.ConvertToAnsi(Byte* pbNativeBuffer, Int32 cbNativeBuffer, Boolean fBestFit, Boolean fThrowOnUnmappableChar)
>          at System.StubHelpers.CSTRMarshaler.ConvertToNative(Int32 flags, String strManaged, IntPtr pNativeBuffer)
>          at SevenZip.NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(String fileName)
>          at SevenZip.SevenZipLibraryManager.LoadLibrary(Object user, Enum format)
>          at SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor.Init(String archiveFullName)
>          at SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor..ctor(String archiveFullName, String password)
>          at AlMadinaLibrary.Packages.Packager.GetFileObject[T](String dibx, String fileName)
>          at TestFile.Form1.LoadDropdownList()

Comment: You tested with the exact same 7z (zipped) file on both machines?

Comment: The first parameter to SevenZipExtractor should be a fully qualified path (e.g. `@"C:\Test.7z"`). Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was the file path was having Unicode characters.

In my local machine my path was `c:\data\myFile.7z` while on other machine it was `c:\میرا ڈیٹا\myFile.7z`.

SevenZip is a dotnet wrapper of native `7z.dll` file and it calls the native `7z.dll` for base functionality.

The exception was coming from the dotnet native `System.String.ConvertToAnsi` function and as it cannot map the Unicode characters. And because the file directory name was in the Unicode characters on other machine so it was throwing exception.